# subtract a string from another string

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to subtract a string from another string and trying to print the rest of the characters of the string. Below is my code:

```
def getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed):
    s="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    k=list(s)
    str1=lettersGuessed
    str2=list(str1)
    if str2[0] in k:
        return k.remove(str2[0])
    else:
        return getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed[1:])
```

Used recursion but getting none as answer. Want to understand what's gone wrong or a better method.

Comment: Does it need to be recursive?

Comment: It doesn't have to be recursive... unless that's your real intention.

Comment: Nope, tried in that way..also tried iterating but feel like am not able to correctly use remove function.

Comment: `s="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  k=list(s)
    x=""
    str1=lettersGuessed
    str2=list(str1)
    for i in range(len(str2)):
        
        if str2[i] in k:
            return k.remove(str2[i])
        else:
            return k`

Comment: Is this an example of what you expect: `'aabbccdd' - 'abc'='abcdd'`?

Comment: `return k.remove(...)` will evaluate to `return None`; `remove` doesn't have any result, it's in-place.

Comment: According to the example provided by @dawg, the relative order of the letters has to be preserved ?

Comment: In your code what exactly are the two strings involved in the extraction?

Comment: one is a-z alphabets and the other is random string, I need a string as output excluding the random string characters.

Comment: What is `'abc'-'aaa'`?

Comment: @Raja _"one is a-z alphabets"_ so the first string is ordered ?

Comment: it looks like you're doing a hangman thing and all you need is so simple: `set(string.ascii_lowercase) - set(lettersGuessed.lower())`

Comment: Thanks to all you guys, got to learn many new things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is very simple. use a set:

```
import string
def getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed):
    return set(string.ascii_lowercase) - set(lettersGuessed.lower())
```

Comment: This produces a different result than what the OP originally said. He said he wanted `'aabbccdd' - 'abc'='abcdd'`. This produces `set('aabbccdd')-set('abc')=set(['d'])`  It is also not order preserving.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
s1='aabbccdd'
s2='abce'

l1=list(s1)
for c in s2:             # c will be each character of the string s2...
    try:
       l1.remove(c)      # try to remove the character...
    except ValueError:   
        # Open question: What if the character in c is not in s1?
        # not specified what 'abc'-'aaa' is or 'abc'-'ace'...
        # just pass -- it is not really defined  
        pass

print '{}-{}={}'.format(s1,s2,''.join(l1))
# aabbccdd-abce=abcdd
```

Comment: May I know why this was downvoted so I may improve the answer?

Answer (score 3):

Use `difference()` method of `sets`

```
str1="sdfjhasdklfd"
str2="sdfjkfdgpoel"

k1=set(str1)
k2=set(str2)

print (k1.difference(k2))
```

Convert them to a set first then find the difference.

Comment: you can just do set subtraction: `k1 - k2`. cleaner and clearer

Comment: @acushner You're right but still cleaner then other answers I think

Answer (score 2):

Removes one occurrence of each of the characters in string `s2` from `s1`:

```
def str_subtract(s1, s2):
    for ch in s2:
        if ch in s1:
            s1 = s1.replace(ch, '', 1)
    return s1

print(str_subtract('aabbccdd', 'abc'))  # --> abcdd
print(str_subtract('aabbccdd', 'abbc'))  # --> acdd
```

Here's another possibly more efficient version.

```
try:
    from functools import reduce  # python 3?
except NameError:
    pass

def str_subtract(s1, s2):
    remove = (ch for ch in s2 if ch in s1)
    return reduce(lambda s, ch: s.replace(ch, '', 1), remove, s1)

print(str_subtract('aabbccdd', 'abc'))  # --> abcdd
print(str_subtract('aabbccdd', 'abbc'))  # --> acdd
```

Comment: Someone doesn't like our answers!  ;-)

Comment: @dawg: Wild guess - it's because we didn't  have a function named `getAvailableLetters()` in our answers.

Answer (score 0):

using recursion is low efficient, try to do this way:

```
def getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed):
    s="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    set_to_remove = set(lettersGuessed)
    return ''.join([c for c in s if c not in set_to_remove])
```

So nice and with a python way!

---

The above solution will eliminate all instance at one time.

A better edition:

```
def getAvailableLetters(s, lettersGuessed):
    k = list(s)
    for c in lettersGuessed:
        try:
            k.remove(c)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return ''.join(k)
```

Comment: It's good to note that this will eliminate all instances of a certain letter. If he only wants to subtract, say, one `a` from `aa`, similar to @dawg's example in the comments, this won't work.

Comment: It worked, but I need to change it to a string again. I can use `"".join` but  where?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first of all, let's say that you have called your function:

```
getAvailableLetters('yourname')
```

then `str2` will have the value:

```
str2 = ['y','o', 'u', 'r', 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e'] ##due to your list method
```

and the value in k will look like:

```
k= ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Now you see `str2` is just a subset of `k` because every letter is inside `k` already from `a-z`.

Then when you remove :

```
if str2[0] in k:
    return k.remove(str2[0])
else:
    return getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed[1:])
```

In the if statement, you're removing what you're trying to return, so obviously, you'll get none.

In else statement, you're making the previously 1st index item 0th. After that it'll also get removed as every alphabet is already in `k`.

```
def getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed):
    s="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    k=list(s)
    str1=lettersGuessed
    str2=list(str1)
    for i in range(len(str2)):
        if str2[i] in k:
            k.remove(str2[i])
    return k
    print(getAvailableLetters('prakash'))
    
    ##this will remove all the characters that are in my name and return the rest of all the elements
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `.replace()` like this:

```
str1 = "UnitedStates"
st2 = "States"
str = str1.replace("States", "")
print(str)
```

The resulting output would be:

```
United
```